# Pointer to stack containers cause program to crash when dereferenced

Tags: c++, pointers, exception, stack, containers

I have a program that makes use of the std containers `vector`, `pair` and `stack`. I have a vector array of type `std::pair` whose elements are pushed onto an `std::stack`. I have a function that prints the contents of the three stacks, two of which are empty. The first stack is printed fine, but the other two stacks which are initially passed as empty, cause Visual Studio to throw an error:

> Exception thrown: read access violation. _Parent_proxy was 0xCCCCCCCC.

The error occurs in line 165 of xutility.

This happens when either of the two other stacks are either empty or nonempty. I have no clue what's causing the issue, since the first stack works fine, but the subsequent two cause the program to crash.

In file main.cpp:

```
void stackPrint(stack<pair<int, char>> _stack) {
    stack<pair<int, char>> temp_stack;
    for (auto i = _stack; !i.empty(); i.pop()) 
        temp_stack.push(i.top());

    while(!temp_stack.empty()) {
        cout << temp_stack.top().first << ", ";
        temp_stack.pop();
    }
}

void print(stack<pair<int, char>>* _stack) {
    cout << "Stack A: ";
    stackPrint(_stack[0]); // function call executes successfully and stackPrint functions properly
    cout << "B: ";
    stackPrint(_stack[1]); // xutility error happens here at function call, stackPrint never invoked
    cout << "C: ";
    stackPrint(_stack[2]); // same here if B is commented out 
}


int main() {
    stack<pair<int, char>> stackA, stackB, stackC;
    int num = 5;

    vector<pair<int, char>> stack_elements(num);

    for (int i = num - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        stack_elements[i].first = i;
        stack_elements[i].second ='A';
        stackA.push(stack_elements[i]);
    }

    //stackB.push(stack_elements[1]);
    //stackC.push(stack_elements[1]);

    stack<pair<int, char>>* stack_array[] = {&stackA, &stackB, &stackC};

    print(*stack_array);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that this function

```
void print(stack<pair<int, char>>* _stack) {
```

takes an array of pointers to stacks, but this isn't the case. Just read the argument type: it's a single pointer to stack. This would be compatible with passing an array of stacks (not pointers to stacks), as the array decays to a pointer.

Now look at the call site:

```
stack<pair<int, char>>* stack_array[] = {&stackA, &stackB, &stackC};

print(*stack_array);
```

you have an array of pointers (which, as I say, this function can't accept), but you dereference that when calling `print`. This is identical to

```
print(stack_array[0]);
```

so, you're passing a pointer to stackA, but `print` assumes that's the first element in an array of stacks. (The fact that stackB and C are declared just after stackA doesn't mean they form an array, they're still unrelated local objects).

You can either change your call site to match `print`'s expectations:

```
stack<pair<int, char>> stacks[3];
stack<pair<int, char>> &stackA = stacks[0];
stack<pair<int, char>> &stackB = stacks[1];
stack<pair<int, char>> &stackC = stacks[2];
// ...
print(stacks)
```

or change both to match your existing `stack_array` type (note the `**`, which is what an array of pointers decays to)

```
void print(stack<pair<int, char>>** _stack);
// ...
print(stack_array);
```

or stop messing around with these decaying arrays with magically hardcoded lengths, and use

```
std::array<std::stack<int,char>, 3> threestacks;
```

or

```
std::vector<std::stack<int,char>> somestacks;
```

Answer (score 0):

`stack_array` definition is

```
stack<pair<int, char>>* stack_array[] = {&stackA, &stackB, &stackC};
```

so `*stack_array` is the first element of `stack_array` which is `&stackA`. Then in function `print` you are using `&stackA` as an array of `stack<pair<int, char>>`. That's undefined behaviour.

`_stack[0]` works fine because it is `stackA`. `_stack[1]` and `_stack[2]` are incorrect